# How do you implement Any<> to find something (preferably case insensitive) in the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I've looked everywhere on the internet. What I've found is that people use Entity's framework to communicate with the Database. There's is a function in this framework called Any<> that mimics Contains() SQL method. I tried to implement the ANY<> method but it doesn't work. It kept giving me conversion type errors.

So my question is this... what is the CORRECT way of implementing ANY<> function. Hope some guru can answer soon. Thanks in advance!

-
So just for some context, I had something like this:

```
   public static List<PhotoAlbumDto> searchAlbumsFromDA(string inputName)
    {
        EzPrintsEntities db = new EzPrintsEntities();
        List<PhotoAlbum> albums = db.PhotoAlbums.ToList().Any(b => b.NAME == inputName);
    }
```

The second like would throw me an :

Error   14  Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'   C:\Users\cding\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication6\EZP.Album.Data\PhotoAlbumDA.cs 22  39  EZP.Album.Data

I think I know the reason why this is giving me an error, but I don't know how to fix it. I'm simply trying to search the database for any PhotoAlbum Objects that matches a certain name.

EDIT: New Question: How do you use Where<> to search for things that match to part of it?

For Example:

User wants to search up: funny

then my search function will return anything that has the word "funny" in it, such as funnygirls, funnydogs, funnypeople, funnybikes, etc...

I implemented the Where<>, but i doesn't do the feature above? Is there any fixes? or any Alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm simply trying to search the database for any PhotoAlbum Objects
>   that matches a certain name.

Why are you wanting to use any?  Any will return a boolean of is there anything in the DB that matches this? Think of it like this:

Any:  Does anything in my list match this?

Where: Give me anything in my list that matches this.

I think you're actually wanting where:

```
db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME == inputName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use where instead like:

```
db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME == inputName)
```

Also don't use ToList before you call other method it moves entire table to memory of your application.

Comment: When should we use ToList and when should we not?

Comment: db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME == inputName).ToList() is ok becouse it first filters the data

Comment: Got it. So always filter data before you create the generic list. Makes sense. But what might happen if someone called ToList() before they filtered it? Is there a negative effect that you had in mind?

Comment: Ohhhh got it... i just played around with the code, and one possibility is conversion errors. Thanks a lot. Very helpful +1 if i could.

Answer (score 1):

Any() is nothing to do with the Entity Framework.

Any() is a LINQ extension method that tries to tell you whether there are either a) any objects in the collection at all or b) any objections in the collection that meet the criteria.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx

You are probably after "Where()", not Any(). Any returns a boolean, Where() will return another collection which meets the criteria you passed in.

The correct way to use Any would be something like:

```
List<string> listOfCars = new List<string>() { "Yellow Car", "Blue Car", "Big Car" };
bool hasYellowCar = listOfCars.Any(c => c == "Yellow Car");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
List<PhotoAlbum> albums = db.PhotoAlbums.Where(b => b.NAME == inputName).ToList();
```